# Build,Unit test,Compile using maven

Tags: xcode, maven, pom.xml

I want to some operation on my xcode project that is compile,build and unit test using the "Maven" command like "mvn clean install","mvn validate". do we need to create Pom.xml? how can we create Pom.xml

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sure, u need pom.xml. how to build your pom? you can read [maven's manual](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html):
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: Thank's for quick response but I would like to create pom.xml from terminal and for all operation like build,compile and unit testing from command line using mvn.

Comment: not sure i understand what u mean. you can still run "mvn clean install" from command line...